# Retarded and advanced Green's function and Feynman propagator

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator, classical-field-theory

1. Is there a use of advanced [Green's functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function_%28many-body_theory%29)? If yes then when or in which context?
2. In quantum field theory, why do we always use Feynman's prescription for finding the [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator) and not the retarded one?
3. Why does Feynman's prescription for the propagator not make sense in a classical field theory?

Answer (score 5):

David Tong notes in his [lecture notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf) that the advanced propagator "is useful if we know the end point of a field configuration and want to figure out where it came from".

Answer (score 4):

1. The *full* Green's function of an equation like the Klein-Gordon equation is the *difference* of the retarded and advanced Green's functions. It is only when the equation in question is an equation involving time that we often discard the advanced anti-causal part to get physically sensible solutions. In QFT, the *full* Green's function appears for example as the expectation value of the commutator of a scalar field with itself.
2. The Feynman propagator is what corresponds to the expectation value of the time ordered product of a field with itself, and it is this time ordered expectation value that appears in the LSZ reduction formula for scattering amplitudes.

Comment: What does "full" Green's function mean?

Comment: @DanielSank: The "full" Green's function is the *actual* Green's function (i.e. the function which gives the Dirac delta when plugged into the equation). The advanced and retarded Green's functions are just the "positive" and "negative" parts of it (the parts that depends on $t >0$ and $t <0$, in a sense).

Comment: Yeah, but aren't the different Green's functions really just the differences in the response when you have different boundary conditions? For example, in a lossy system (I'm thinking of circuits but this is true for other systems) you want the retarded function because it's the one where the disturbance emenates out from a source and doesn't come back.

Comment: @DanielSank: True. I call the *mathematical definition of the Green's function* the "full" Green's function because it is an abstract property of the equation. Whether you have to use this full version or the retarded version or even possibly something else is a *physical* choice not inherent to the equation.

Comment: I think I'm trying to point out that an e.g. differential equation without boundary conditions is ambiguous.

Comment: @ACuriousMind  The difference of the advanced and retarded Green functions is called *causal propagator*, $E(x,y)$. It is not, properly speaking, a Green function, since it does not satisfy the standard requirement of Green functions $P_x G(x,y) = \delta(x,y)$. This is due to the presence of the *minus* sign $E(x,y) = A(x,y)-R(x,y)$ which implies $P_xE(x,y)=0$. Nevertheless $E$ defines a map form the space $C_0^\infty(M)$ of smooth compactly supported functions $f$  to the space $S$ of smooth Cauchy compactly supported solutions $\psi$ of the field equation: $\psi(x) = \int_M E(x,y) f(y) dy$

Comment: That linear map is surjective, continuous in the appropriate topologies, and its kernel is made of the functions $Pg$ with $g \in C_0^\infty(M)$.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read how these division of the Fenyman propagator appear for scalar fields, in advanced and delayed components, through the expected value, in the vacuum state for the temporally ordered product, of a scalar field with itself.
Read in QFT Ryder pages 193-194